# HTML Forms POST method submits to Self but null array to action file

Tags: html, form-submit

I am not a novice. This seems very simple. But I have been going crazy last two days.

I have suddenly started facing this issue.

A simple HTML form submits GET variables to itself and to action file. However, POST method returns NULL in the action file.

HTML test.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="yourname"><input type="submit" name="inpsub">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

in test2.php Returns array(0) { }

Could it be a browser issue ?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in .htaccess or similar going on? You could also try var_dump($_REQUEST) to see what might be happening/they show up.

Comment: Thanks a ton @JeffVdovjak !!! You saved my life !! It was a .htacces issue. I removed the htaccess file and it works ! Now I will sit down and identify the rewrite that is causing the error !! Please post this as Answer and I will accept it

Comment: It is the external redirect code in .htaccess to hide file extension that is causing this issue. ## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff Vdovjak !

I have solved this

It was an internal redirect code in .htaccess to hide file extension that was causing this issue.

```
## hide .php extension 
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Commenting out the conditions is working like a charm !

Comment: No problem :) Glad you found the rewrite rule. Accept your own answer ;)  There are even badges for it -- so you're not "cheating". (Sorry, I'm doing homework at the same time ... I got lost for a bit in it!)

Comment: Please do post the Answer. I would love to accept that which is rightful :) I posted the Answer only so that others can know the solution till the time you post. Please do me the favour and post the answer ..I will take down mine... :)